# Is it sometime good to give priorities to classes over advanced CSS selectors for better understanding?

Tags: css

For example my code is this .I'm only having **2** items under the `#contacts` div.

```
#contacts {list-style:none; overflow:hidden; margin-left:7px; margin-bottom:10px}
.address { float:left}
.tel { float:right}
```

I can also do the same with this

```
#contacts {list-style:none; overflow:hidden; margin-left:7px; margin-bottom:10px}
#contacts span:first-child { float:left}
#contacts span:last-child { float:left}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather use

```
#contacts .address {...}
#contacts .tel {...}
```

or even better if you need to float both

```
#contacts .address, #contacts .tel {float:left;}
```

In case some day you have to add `.fax` too you have much less work to do. Also i think this is much more clear to understand for a programmer that will pick up the code after you.

Comment: The code I give was just for example. my questions is pseudo elements or advanced selectors Vs classes. But your answer is also helpful to me. +1

Answer (score 1):

The `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo elements make sense if the children don't convey specific information. If the child elements (as in this case) do convey specific details, then classes (or better still, [HTML5 microdata attributes](http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html)) are more suitable.